# Looking for a sci fi book about a girl with eyes that changed colour

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I read this book maybe 10 years ago, it was set on this ship where they found a young stowaway with eyes that changed colour based on her mood. I think her name might have started with an "R" and it was based around her running away from her home planet as she was telepathic and they would have killed her or something.

Does anyone know what this book is?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! You have a good start here but if you can take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and [edit] in any extra details you can remember it would help with identifying your story.

Comment: The changing eye color is a fairly common idea in literature. While there's a lot of them on the TV-Tropes page [Mood Ring Eyes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MoodRingEyes), none of them jump out right away as a match. If we could have any extra details you can remember it might help narrow things down.

Comment: I'm also looking for this book! I remember that she would sing and it would impact the crew, and she could breath under water or at least hold her breath a really long time? I believe the title started with the letter A and was like a made up word. Also keen to find this book if anyone has any leads

Answer (score 4):

I found the book! It is called [Roivan by New Zealand Author Glynne MacLean](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3586064-roivan).

> "Her instructions were clear: travel to human space. Once in human space, stay there. Do not return. Speak only your name. Do not take the test. protect your mind. Do not speak of your world, your life or your species until you meet someone who tells you first."
>
> Joshua Carter is alarmed to discover Roivan, a member of a telepathic, telekinetic and amphibian species, stowing away on his ship. Joshua must discover where she is from and what she wants.

It's out of print but I've emailed the author to see if there is any copies left